# what is the metric and dimension for getting Page Path in Google Analytics?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have tried the following code to get the Page Path.

```
DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest pagePathRequestRequest = services.Data.Ga.Get(String.Format("ga:{0}", profileid), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "ga:pagePath");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct dimension, it is `ga:pagePath`. Be aware, that it returns everything after the hostname, so if the page is www.mywebsite.com/someUrl, the value of ga:pagePath will be someUrl. Try [GA query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) before writing any code. Thing is, the metrics and dimensions you pass might be incompatible with ga:pagePath dimension. You can check whether your metrics and dimensions are compatible [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

**Update**

This is the example of how do I get the report with page urls and number of user visits on them using google analytics v3

```
public IList<IList<string>> ExecuteQuery(string ids, string metrics, string dimensions, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) 
{
     var formattedStartDate = startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     var formattedEndDate = endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

     var request = _analyticsService.Get(ids, formattedStartDate, formattedEndDate, metrics);

     request.Dimensions = dimensions;
     request.MaxResults = 10000;
     request.SamplingLevel = GetRequest.SamplingLevelEnum.HIGHERPRECISION;

     var result = new List<IList<string>>();
     var response = request.Execute();
     result.AddRange(response.Rows);

     return result;
}
...
var data = ExecuteQuery(ids, "ga:users", "ga:pagePath", startDate, endDate);
```

My `_analyticsService` is equivalent to your `services.Data.Ga`. `ga:pagePath` is a dimension, not a metric, you can't execute a query with no metrics and a dimension, it is specified in another way.

Comment: Thanks. But I checked with this. Couldn't find the solution. It returns only count. But not the URLs.